# How to do proper testing?

Tags: java, testing, domain-driven-design

Up until now I've written code without really giving a thought to whether it was fully bug proof or not. I'm familiar with JUnit and have a vague idea of how I can use it to test methods and such. What sort of tests can I do beyond that?

P.S: I know it's a potentially vast topic. I just need a few leads so I can do some reading.

Answer (score 2):

There's using JUnit, and then there's test driven development.  Yes, use JUnit, but more importantly, learn what test driven development is.  It will improve your coding and design significantly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [V model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model_%28software_development%29) of software development which will give you a good overview of the levels at which you should test your software